# What is the meaning of the empty `TextData` column in the mssql Profiler screen?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I added `SP:StmtStarting` and   `SP:StmtCompleted` as columns then after running the trace I got this empty `TextData` columns (colored in blue in the picture below).
What is the meaning of those empty `TextData` column in the mssql Profiler screen?

[image]